# Applying last valid index mask to dataframe to get last valid values

Tags: python, performance, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
    s1        s2       s3       s4
0   v1        v2       v3       v4
0   v5        v6       v7       np.nan
0   v8      np.nan     v9       np.nan
0   v10     np.nan     np.nan   np.nan
```

Essentially from top down there are numerical values and across columns at some random index values will switch to np.nan only.

I've used .apply(pd.Series.last_valid_index) to get the indexes for which the values are still numerical, however, I'm not sure of the most efficient way to retrieve a series for which I have the actual value at the last valid index.

Ideally I'd be able to derive a series that looks like:

```
   value
s1 v10
s2 v6
s3 v9
s4 v4
```

or as a dataframe that looks like

```
   s1 s2 s3 s4
0 v10 v6 v9 v4
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one way using NumPy indexing:

```
# ensure index is normalised
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

# calculate last valid index across dataframe
idx = df.apply(pd.Series.last_valid_index)

# create result using NumPy indexing
res = pd.Series(df.values[idx, np.arange(df.shape[1])],
                index=df.columns,
                name='value')

print(res)

s1    v10
s2     v6
s3     v9
s4     v4
Name: value, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is another way to do it, without resetting the index:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x[x.notnull()].values[-1])

s1    v10
s2     v6
s3     v9
s4     v4
```

Comment: Nice solution +1, would you know if `last_valid_index` is more or less efficient than Boolean indexing via `pd.Series.notnull` ?

Comment: Thanks, Not sure, but it should be easy to test... give me a second

Comment: Based on a super crude test on a large df, I think that `last_valid_index` is actually quite a bit faster than `notnull()`

Comment: Thanks for testing. Yeh I thought so, maybe `last_valid_index` goes backwards like a generator rather than testing each and every item.

Comment: `x[x.notnull()]` can be replaced with `x.dropna()`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to normalize the index, find the last valid index per column and create a dataframe from it.

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
ser = df.apply(lambda x: x.last_valid_index())
pd.DataFrame([df[col][ser[col]] for col in df.columns], index=df.columns).T
```

Output:

```
     s1 s2  s3  s4
0   v10 v6  v9  v4
```

Also, this way, your original `df` stays intact.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I tried this but I get the following error:
TypeError: cannot do label indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex'> with these indexers [nan] of <class 'numpy.float64'>

Comment: Are you sure, it is coming from my code? Which line? What version are you running for pandas?

Comment: It seems the be the second line:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-106-584f73a55d2a>", line 26, in <module>
    print(pd.DataFrame([df.reset_index()[col][ser[col]] for col in df.columns], index=df.columns).T)

TypeError: cannot do label indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex'> with these indexers [nan] of <class 'numpy.float64'>

Comment: `df.reset_index()[col].iloc[ser[col]]`, does that work for you? If so, I would update my answer. I am using '0.23.0' version for pandas. It works for me. Which version are you using?

Comment: I figured it out, I had to drop columns where all the values were np.nan - then it works like a charm! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using `groupby()`

```
df.stack().groupby(level=1).last()
```

Output:

```
s1    v10
s2     v6
s3     v9
s4     v4
```

and as a df:

```
df.stack().groupby(level=1).last().to_frame().T
```

Output:

```
    s1  s2  s3  s4
0  v10  v6  v9  v4
```