# Return values between index n and last non NaN index in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to return the values of the last N rows that are non NaN in a pandas dataframe, in order to perform some operations. To make it clearer, say I want to compute the mean of the last 3 non NaN rows.
First, this is what my dataframe looks like:

```
           a           b         c  
0   125384.0    0.823381  614109.0  
1   224996.0    0.926270  522097.0  
2   178755.0    0.865229  482718.0 
3   194345.0    0.959907  473543.0 
4   143193.0         NaN  450413.0 
5        NaN         NaN       NaN
```

For column `a`, for example, I want the mean between `178755.0`, `194345.0` and `143193.0` (3 last rows before the first NaN). Expected result: `172097.7`

So far I tried 2 approaches: first what was proposed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22403469/locate-first-and-last-non-nan-values-in-a-pandas-dataframe), and used `pd.Series.last_valid_index` as the second input in `iloc`:

```
df.iloc[-3: df.apply(pd.Series.last_valid_index)].mean()
```

Which gave me the following error:

```
TypeError: cannot do positional indexing on RangeIndex with these indexers
```

I thought that the problem here was that I was retrieving an index, which made me try retrieving the value itself, and used what was proposed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50861003/applying-last-valid-index-mask-to-dataframe-to-get-last-valid-values):

```
df.iloc[-3: df.apply(lambda x: x[x.notnull()].values[-1])]
```

This again gave me the same error:

```
TypeError: cannot do positional indexing on RangeIndex with these indexers
```

Some insight into what the solution might be would be very much appreciated. I want to do this for all columns in the dataframe, hence using `df.apply`. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x[x.notnull()].iloc[-3:].mean(), axis = 0)
```

Comment: This did exactly what I was asking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Let us try `stack`

```
df.stack().groupby(level=1).apply(lambda x : x.tail(3).mean())
Out[11]: 
a    172097.666667
b         0.917135
c    468891.333333
```

Comment: This does work, however I have columns with the same name and I believe it's computing the mean of the last 3 rows between all of them (mean of means). Anyway, thanks for the reply!